# How to perform Set transformations on RDD's with different number of columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two `RDD`s. One `RDD` is of type `RDD[(String, String, String)]` and the second `RDD` is of type `RDD[(String, String, String, String, String)]`. Whenever I try to perform operations like union, intersection, etc, I get the error :-

```
error: type mismatch;
found: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String, String,String, String)]
required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String, String)]
   uid.union(uid1).first()
```

How can I perform the set operations in this case? If set operations are not possible at all, what can I do to get the same result as set operations without having the type mismatch problem?

**EDIT:**

Here's a sample of the first lines from both the RDDs :

```
(" p69465323_serv80i"," 7 "," fb_406423006398063"," guest_861067032060185_android"," fb_100000829486587"," fb_100007900293502") 

(fb_100007609418328,-795000,r316079113_serv60i)
```

Comment: Join operation is defined only on PairwiseRDDs. You need to map your rdd in pairwiseRDD.

Comment: You cannot perform a union of two RDDs of differents types.

Comment: @ЮлийЩербак the OP isn't performing any join operation to be needing a PairRDD

Comment: Thats's why the question, what can I do to get past the type mismatch problem??

Comment: You can't past the mismatch unless you transform one the two RDDs into the type of the other. And not knowing what each field represent, I can't give a concrete answer about that.

Comment: Here's a sample of the first lines from both the RDDs :-                       (String, String, String, String, String, String) = (" p69465323_serv80i"," 7 "," fb_406423006398063"," guest_861067032060185_android"," fb_100000829486587"," fb_100007900293502")                             (String, String, String) = (fb_100007609418328,-795000,r316079113_serv60i) @ eliasah

Comment: @AviAggarwal please use the edit button to add information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Several operations require two `RDD`s to have the same type.

Let's take `union` for example: `union` basically *concatenates* two `RDD`s. As you can imagine it would be unsound to concatenate the following:

```
RDD1
(1, 2)
(3, 4)

RDD2
(5, 6, "string1")
(7, 8, "string2")
```

As you see, `RDD2` has one extra column. One thing that you can do, is work on `RDD1` to that its schema matches that of `RDD2`, for example by adding a default value:

```
RDD1
(1, 2)
(3, 4)

RDD1 (AMENDED)
(1, 2, "default")
(3, 4, "default")

RDD2
(5, 6, "string1")
(7, 8, "string2")

UNION
(1, 2, "default")
(3, 4, "default")
(5, 6, "string1")
(7, 8, "string2")
```

You can achieve this with the following code:

```
val sc: SparkContext = ??? // your SparkContext

val rdd1: RDD[(Int, Int)] =
  sc.parallelize(Seq((1, 2), (3, 4)))

val rdd2: RDD[(Int, Int, String)] =
  sc.parallelize(Seq((5, 6, "string1"), (7, 8, "string2")))

val amended: RDD[(Int, Int, String)] =
  rdd1.map(pair => (pair._1, pair._2, "default"))

val union: RDD[(Int, Int, String)] =
  amended.union(rdd2)
```

If you know print the contents

```
union.foreach(println)
```

you will get what we ended up having in the above example.

Of course, the exact semantics of how you want the two `RDD`s to match depend on your problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I mentioned in my comment. An empty string would do as well. :)

Comment: the RDDs come from reading data from two different csv files and performing mapping operations on them. Will your solution still work? Also I have to take into account that the files are pretty large in size (~1 GB each).

Comment: @AviAggarwal this solution should work but you have to test it.