# How to map one column of RDD with other columns of the (a)same (b)different RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Beginner here, I'm working with Spark 2.1.1 and Scala 2.11.8.

I have an RDD with six columns. This is the first entry of the RDD :-

```
(String, String, String, String, String, String) = (" p69465323_serv80i"," 7 "," fb_406423006398063"," guest_861067032060185_android"," fb_100000829486587"," fb_100007900293502")
```

The actual RDD has more than 5 million entries.

I want to map the first column individually with the third, fourth, fifth and sixth columns in such a manner that I get something like :-

```
(fb_406423006398063, p69465323_serv80i)
(guest_861067032060185_android, p69465323_serv80i)
(fb_100000829486587, p69465323_serv80i)
(fb_100007900293502, p69465323_serv80i)
```

i.e the first column is mapped individually with third, fourth, fifth and sixth columns. How can I do this (a) In the same RDD (b) In different RDDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have an Array of Tuples in which each element is like :

```
(" p69465323_serv80i"," 7 "," fb_406423006398063"," guest_861067032060185_android"," fb_100000829486587"," fb_100007900293502")
```

You can use the following:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array((" p69465323_serv80i"," 7 "," fb_406423006398063"," guest_861067032060185_android"," fb_100000829486587"," fb_100007900293502")))
val pairedRdd = rdd.map(x => ((x._1, x._3), (x._1, x._4), (x._1, x._5), (x._1, x._6)) )
pairedRdd.collect
Array[((String, String), (String, String), (String, String), (String, String))] = Array(((" p69465323_serv80i"," fb_406423006398063"),(" p69465323_serv80i"," guest_861067032060185_android"),(" p69465323_serv80i"," fb_100000829486587"),(" p69465323_serv80i"," fb_100007900293502")))
```

Comment: Thanks!! But I have a question here, will the same solution work for two different RDDs? This is with respect to a question I posted earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44819655/how-to-perform-set-transformations-on-rdds-with-different-number-of-columns

Comment: @AviAggarwal You mean map columns from one rdd to another? no, you can't do that with this. The solution provided on that question looks good. As suggested there, both your RDDs need to be of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder
import spark.implicits._

//val yourRDD = (" p69465323_serv80i"," 7 "," fb_406423006398063"," guest_861067032060185_android"," fb_100000829486587"," fb_100007900293502")
val newDF = yourRDD
  .map(_.split(","))
  .map(attributes => YourModelClass(attributes(0),attributes(1), 
   attributes(2), attributes(3), attributes(4) ))
  .toDF()
 // Register the DataFrame as a temporary view
newDF.createOrReplaceTempView("DFTable")

val firstDF = spark.sql("SELECT secondCol, firstCol FROM DFTable")
val secondDF = spark.sql("SELECT thirdCol, firstCol FROM DFTable")
// val thirdDF = .... etc
```

Declare **YourModelClass** object or class with variables: firstCol, secondCol,... fiftCol.

I hope that help you